# is access to array member in structure in c a access to value or address?

Tags: c, arrays, string

In the following code:

```
struct a  {
    char name[18];
}customer;
scanf("%s",customer.name);
printf("%s",customer.name); 
struct a *pt=&customer;    `
```

Because of pointing array name to the first element of that, is `customer.name` pointing to the first element of this member?

In a book it was wrote that  `*(customer.name+2)` is equivalent with `customer.name[2]` and `pt->name[2]`. But I cant understand these note and also  why `customer.name` in `scanf()` function is an address and in `printf()` function isn't address?

Comment: Under certain uses, an array is represented as a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`customer.name` is a pointer to the first character in the `name` character array.

`customer.name` is equivalent to `&(customer.name[0])`

`customer.name` convention is a typical way to access character array in the structures.

In `printf()` `%s` format requires pointer to the first element of the array.

The structure `a`, the member `name` array, and `name[0]` character has exactly the same address in the memory. You can see that in the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct a  {
    char name[18];
}customer;

int main()
{
    customer bob;
    customer *ptr; 

    scanf("%s",bob.name);
    printf("Customer name is: %s\n",bob.name); 

    ptr = & bob;  

    printf("Memory Address of the bob structure is:  %p\n", (void *) ptr);    
    printf("Memory Address of the 'bob.name'    is:  %p\n", (void *) &bob.name);
    printf("Memory Address of the 'bob.name[0]' is:  %p\n", (void *) &(bob.name[0]) );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Bob
Customer name is: Bob
Memory Address of the bob structure is:  0x7ffe0d7687e0
Memory Address of the 'bob.name'    is:  0x7ffe0d7687e0
Memory Address of the 'bob.name[0]' is:  0x7ffe0d7687e0
```

Answer (score 2):

In both the examples for `print()` and `scanf()` here, `customer.name` resolves to a pointer to the first element of the array `name` which is a member of `customer` variable of type `struct a`.

To clear the confusion, in case of `%s` format specifier with `printf()` the argument type expected is pointer to the first element of the array. So, in case of this `printf()` call, the argument `customer.name` is correct, it's a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

When array is used as a function argument then it decay to pointer to its first element. In both of the functions `scanf` and `printf` the argument `customer.name` is converted to pointer and have type `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, it is an address. However, one of them uses that address to fill the string, and the other one uses the address to read the value.

In `printf` when you use `%s`, the function needs the start address of that string. You should not be misunderstood by the case of `int i = 10; printf("%d", i");` which value of the variable is passed to the `printf`. The story of string in print function is different as you've seen.

Answer (score 1):

In ***this case*** in `scanf` ***you passed the address ultimately*** because *the array decays into pointer to first element*.(Some cases where this decay doesn't occur is `sizeof`,`AlignOf` or address of operator `&` etc). And that pointer contains the address of the first element of the array.

```
scanf("%s",customer.name);
           ^^^^
```

The pointer to the first element of the array being a `char*` holds the address needed by `scanf` to write the value into the desired memory address. To clarify a bit, you can even pass this equivalently:(The previous discussion explains why it is possible).

```
scanf("%s",&customer.name[0]);
```

In the `printf` also ***it is an address which is being passed*** in the same logic as before and that is in turn used by `print` to `print` the characters contained by it until it reaches the `\0`.

From [**standard 7.21.6.6**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.6) Under `frpintf` function description:

> If no `l` length modifier is present, ***the argument shall be a pointer to
>   the initial element of an array of character type***.280) Characters from
>   the array are written up to (but not including) the terminating null
>   character. If the precision is specified, no more than that many bytes
>   are written. If the precision is not specified or is greater than the
>   size of the array, the array shall contain a null character

As a thumb rule - in case of `scanf` you ***would always pass the address*** of the variable on which the inputted data will be stored. In case `printf` it depends on the format specifier used - just like shown above the `%s` format specifier expects an address but `%d` or `%c` specifier doesn't.